# Is there any way to get data from logitech lua log console?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm doing some code for my logitech mouse with lua but I can't find any way to communicate with my pc at all. No lib available here so I can't even send smth to cmd, write file, launch .bat and etc. At least I wasn't successful at this.

The only place where you can output some info is the log window. So the title asks main problem of this topic: Is there any way to get data from logitech lua log console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To run a .bat file from LGS Lua script:***

Create a shortcut action

- Run 'Logitech Gaming Software' application
- Open 'Customise buttons' tab
- Select profile
- In the left side you will see the 'Commands' pane (list of bindable actions such as keyboard keys, macros, etc), press the big 'plus' sign to add new command.
- In the 'Command Editor', select the 'Shortcut' in the left pane

  - Set the 1st text field 'Name'              to `RUN_BAT_FILE`
  - Set the 2nd text field 'Enter a shortcut'  to `your_bat_file.bat`
  - Set the 3rd text field 'Working Directory' to `C:\Path\to\folder`
- Press 'OK' button to close the 'Command Editor'

Now you can:

- either bind this action to a mouse button (drag-n-drop action `RUN_BAT_FILE` from `Commands` pane to the big picture of the mouse)
- or invoke this action from your LGS Lua script by `PlayMacro("RUN_BAT_FILE")`

Please note that console window will be brought to the front, and your game will switch off fullscreen mode and will lose keyboard focus.
That is a very nasty thing while you're playing.
But you can invoke windowless applications without interfering the game.

---

***To pass a long message from LGS Lua script to external program:***

You can send strings by invoking `OutputDebugMessage` in your LGS script
and receive them in your external program by means of [`LGS Debug Interceptor.dll`](https://gondwanasoftware.net.au/lgsdi.shtml).

---

***To pass information from your external program to your LGS Lua script:***

The best way I'm aware of is the following:
Your external program can create a .lua-file and your LGS Lua script can execute it and receive the result (a tuple of Lua values `return`ed by this script)

```
data = dofile[[c:\some_script.lua]]
```

Comment: Solution was easier then I thought :D
Thanks a lot <3